# Angular7- Is there a way to add two values to bindLabel

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to create a ng-select with 2 values in my labelbind  currently my ng-select is as follows

```
 <ng-select [items]="mentorSessions"
                       [multiple]="false"
                       [closeOnSelect]="true"
                       [searchable]="true"
                       bindLabel="name"
                       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                       [(ngModel)]="mentorToShareTo">
  </ng-select>
```

I would like the bindLabel to be something like this

```
bindLabel="name" + ":" +"profession"
```

Comment: I'm sorry  , I'm a student and am new to angular . I'm reading that the bindLabel accepts a string value , so "name"+ "profession" will be read as "nameprofession" so i did not know how to go forward with my issue

Comment: also my answer is what i have attempted , and it does not work

Comment: I get that you're new to Angular and a student, but again, that doesn't exempt you from reading [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) ! We're here to **resolve issues** encountered with your code, not to *code for you* or *teach you basics*. Consider reading [ask] before posting a question, and in case of an issue (a real one), please provide a [mcve] !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either create a new property on your objects, where you combine your properties in a way you want that to be displayed, and bind that new property to *bindLabel*, or according to the [docs](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates), you can create a custom label template:

```
<ng-select ...>
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        {{item.name}}:{{item.profession}}
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We all been learning, don't bash someone just 'cause they haven't stumbled upon something you consider basic.

Even if bindLabel accepts a string you can form one this way:

```
[bindLabel]="name + ':' + profession"
```

Your modified code will look like this

```
<ng-select [items]="mentorSessions"
           [multiple]="false"
           [closeOnSelect]="true"
           [searchable]="true"
           [bindLabel]="name + ':' + profession"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
           [(ngModel)]="mentorToShareTo">
</ng-select>
```